# how to update a list and not have it remove previous input

Tags: python, list, function

i'm new to programming, currently working on my first program. i'm trying to add a dict to a list and have it store it, every time i update the list with a new input, the last input gets erased. help!!!

i have a feeling that it has something to do with directly updating the list rather then having a mediator. maybe?

```py
def newfood(food, caloric):
    foodList = []
    newFoodList = ({food:caloric})
    foodList.append(newFoodList)
    print(foodList)
```

apple:33, cherry:34, Mlife:42

every time it gets a new input it should update the list to have the old dicts and the new ones too

Comment: make foodList a global variable. i.e. define it in main scope of program

Comment: Move `foodList` outside your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by others, the problem is that you're modifying a variable that won't be available outside the function.

One solution is to declare foodList `global`:

```
def newfood(food, caloric):
    global foodList
    foodList = []
    newFoodList = ({food:caloric})
    foodList.append(newFoodList)
    print(foodList)

newfood('apple', 100)
```

Another would be to declare `foodList` outside the function, but this is a risky way of doing things: depending on how you write your code, you could end up 'shadowing' the global variable.

```
foodList = []
def newfood(food, caloric):
    newFoodList = ({food:caloric})
    foodList.append(newFoodList)
    print(foodList)

newfood('apple', 100)
```

The best solution is probably to have the function return what you're after, or write it so that it modifies a list it is given:

```
def newfood(foodList, afood, acaloric):
    return foodList + [{afood:acaloric}]

foodList = []
foodList = newfood(foodList, 'apple', 100)
print(foodList)
```

Or:

```
def newfood(afoodlist, afood, acaloric):
    foodList.append({afood:acaloric})

foodList = []
newfood(foodList, 'apple', 100)
print(foodList)
```

Or, given what you're doing, writing the whole thing as a class:

```
class FoodList(list):
    def add(self, food, caloric):
        self.append({food:caloric})

foodList = FoodList()
foodList.add('apple', 100)
print(foodList)
```

Note: You're creating a `newFoodList` as `({food:caloric})` - however, that's really just a `dict` dictionary, the parentheses don't do anything in this case. The alternatives shown here do the same, but it seems like you're not really after a list of dictionaries, so you should probably reconsider your data structure.

Comment: i was trying to store a food item and its caloric value per serving so i figured that a dict was a good way to store the data, witch later i could pop the value of a certain food and multiply by X amount of serving a user had. Thanks for including multiple ways of solving my problem, its very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The list `foodList` is defined inside of your function. Because of that, every time you call the function, it is adding the value to the empty list. You need to move the list outside of the function (above `def newfood(food, caloric):`). Then you will be able to access the list from outside the function.

Comment: thanks, such an easy fix lol, does this mean i can call on the list with any other function that i create since its outside and ""free""?

Comment: You don't need to "move it outside", you can also just add `global foodList` at the start of the function, or even better would be to `return foodList` at the end of the function and assign it to some variable from wherever you're calling the function.

Comment: @Grismar There are many ways to skin a cat. Depending on what he's trying to do, returning the value, setting it globally, whatever. My main point was that how he has it, he can't save the state of the list, so he has to "move it outside the function" as I stated before.

Comment: I agree, but since @anthonypizarro appears to be new to the language, sending him away with what he indicates appears to think is a "fix" isn't really helping, so I figured I'd point that out.